# Remap shared library on a child process

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, fork, loader, mmap

Parent is forking a new child.

This child inherits the parent shared library libfoo.so
If I look at the child process memory map related to libfoo.so, the virtual mapping are the same of the parent (as it should, since doing a fork())

I would like to be able to remap the child shared library (libfoo.so), to a different virtual mapping, (which is of course different from the parent)

Do you have an idea ? or off-the-shelf solution for it ?
is it possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally impossible. Dynamic loader loads and relocates libraries on `spawn` and you shouldn't attempt calling it directly from running code.

Even in case you can somehow fit in the call of dynamic loader, it would like to start clean (meaning it will want to relocate itself, but it's already relocated…). It will also want to load and relocate *all* libraries, not just one of them.

So, simply speaking, there's no interface for doing this in Glibc and probably every other C library.

Then, there are also different formats of relocation information. In case of x86 and x86-64 it's `RELA`, meaning the relocations have explicit addends in separate table, and hence it's possible (in principle) to edit addresses again. But on ARM, the relocations are `REL`, meaning addends are implicit and are lost (overwritten) once you do the relocation.

You should look at `dlopen` and co. — maybe they'll fit your purpose.

Comment: Yes, the platform is ARM,

Comment: Can you elaborate why it can't be done? how does the PLT & GOT works ? can't I forced them to revert to state on unresolved symobols ?  Regarding dlopen how that will help if the library mapping is remapped ? since the child is calling function from the old mapping, how can I use dlopen in this case to resolve all the missing mapping in the new virtual map? anyway I would like just to remap the .text section, The reason I want to remap a "forked" library mapping is because ASLR is inherited in  child process, & I would like to have randomization in the child process

Comment: @omri-c Then maybe you should not directly fork and use i.e. `system()` to get yourself a new process in another randomized space?